# Get middle term from list of sentences using start and end phrases

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of sentences, I need to find the start phrase and end phrase in that sentence if present and get the middle element. If the middle element has more than one word it should skip and move to the next occurrence.

#### list of sentences

```
para_list = [["hello sir good afternoon calling to you from news18 curious"],["a pleasant welcome from enws18 team what can i"], ["hi a good afternoon sir from news18"]]
```

#### start phrase

```
to_find_s =['good','afternoon']
```

#### end phrase

```
to_find_l = ['from','news18']
```

#### Code

```
for i, w in enumerate(para_list):
    l = [sentence for sentence in w if all(word in w for word in to_find_s)]
    if l:
        m = [sentence for sentence in w if all(word in w for word in to_find_l)
```

#### Output

I am getting the sentences in which the phrases are present but not able to get the middle term

#### Expected Output

```
list = ['sir'] #from the last list. There would not be any item from first list as it has two words in between-'to you'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function will do the work.

```
def find_middle_phrase(para_list, to_find_s, to_find_l):
    output_list = []
    start_phrase, end_phrase = " ".join(to_find_s), " ".join(to_find_l)
    for para in para_list:
        para_string = para[0]
        if para_string.find(start_phrase)!=-1 and para_string.find(end_phrase)!=-1:
            required_phrase_starting_index = para_string.index(start_phrase) + len(start_phrase)
            required_phrase_ending_index = para_string.index(end_phrase)
            required_output_string = para_string[required_phrase_starting_index: required_phrase_ending_index].strip()
            if required_output_string.find(" ") == -1:
                output_list.append(required_output_string)
    return output_list
```

EXAMPLE:

```
para_list = [["hello sir good afternoon calling to you from news18 curious"],["a pleasant welcome from enws18 team what can i"], ["hi a good afternoon sir from news18"]]
to_find_s =['good','afternoon']
to_find_l = ['from','news18']
expected_output = find_middle_phrase(para_list, to_find_s, to_find_l)
print(expected_output)
```

Got output:

```
['sir']
```

Comment: if there are multiple words in between start and end phrase I want to ignore the sentence. 
                                                                                                                                   
para_list = [["hello sir good afternoon calling to you from news18 curious"],["a pleasant welcome from enws18 team what can i"], ["hi a good afternoon sir from news18"]].                            I have edited the first sentence from list- added multiple words between phrases. What changes should I have to make

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly @ArunGeorge

Answer (score 1):

This produces the expected output:

```
for sentence in para_list:
    words = sentence[0].split()
    for i in range(len(words) - 3):
        if(words[i] == to_find_s[0] and words[i+1] == to_find_s[1]):
            if(words[i+3] == to_find_l[0] and words[i+4] == to_find_l[1]):
                m = words[i+2]
                print(m)
```